# bool function with pointers to C strings as arguments/parameters

Tags: c++, boolean

I have this Uni assignment(part of reading csv file in C++) and I couldn't understand exactly what I can do. One of the instruction is to define a C++ bool function with two Pointers to C strings as arguments. The function checks whether the string pointed by the first parameter pointer is part of the string pointed by the second parameter pointer and turns a Boolean value.
Something like...   function_name ("babies","babies are adorable") returns true as                function_name("Radio","Entertainment tonight") returns false.

Comment: What have you tried? In SO, most "write me X code" posts only get negative votes.

Comment: Use [std::search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) to find the substrings.

Comment: so far I tried bool isPartof(char *key ,char *search)

Comment: use `const char*` instead of just `char*` for the string arguments. Use `strstr` to find the substring of the first in the second. Return the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) to easily determine if a string contains a specific substring.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

bool isPartof(const char *key, const char *search)
{
    const char *searchEnd = search + std::strlen(search);
    return std::search(search, searchEnd, key, key + std::strlen(key)) != searchEnd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like `strstr`? The difference is that the standard library function has the haystack first, and returns a pointer to the first occurrence rather than a Boolean value. If you can use standard library functions, then you can just define this one in terms of `strstr`. Otherwise, you can loop through the haystack, searching for the first character of the needle, and for every occurrence of the first character, check if it starts an occurrence of the entire needle.